# Does Minecraft Pi use the GPU?

Tags: pi-zero-w, minecraft, memory-split

I'm trying to figure out how I should split the memory on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. All I use it for is testing my Python 3 Minecraft Pi code that I write on my computer, push to Github, and pull using the Pi. I'm sure `git pull` does not use the GPU whatsoever, but I want to know whether Minecraft Pi uses the GPU, the CPU, or both, and if both, which is predominant. I have the OpenGL Full KMS driver enabled if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by predominant? Arguably, the CPU part is predominant in any practical application, even if it uses the GPU.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That's what I mean. Thank you for your reply. Now I know that if it uses both CPU and GPU then I should give the CPU more. Unless you are wrong of course.

Comment: Java apps tend to like a lot of RAM.

Comment: @goldilocks So Minecraft Pi is written in Java? Also, does it use the GPU, CPU, or both? Sorry if I'm being a noob.

Comment: Basically what would be a good CPU/GPU split for a Pi that is only responsible for pulling code from git, running it, and playing MCPI.

Comment: I don't know the extent to which OpenES-GL (the graphics lib that exploits the GPU) can benefit from increasing amounts of (GPU) memory; I think it can be dissimiliar from RAM usage (wherein a process needs a specific amount at any given point in time, and having more than that won't make any difference) in this sense.  You should try and get a handle on how much RAM is actually being used by the system while playing -- either by arranging snapshots in the background, or by logging in remotely and checking that way.

Comment: *"So Minecraft Pi is written in Java?"* Yeah, pretty sure all versions of Minecraft are Java based, although they may allow for scripting in languages like python.  I'm not an actual Minecraft user, or gamer generally, though.

Comment: @goldilocks I just found out it's written in C++. Would you have any comment on C++ RAM usage?

Comment: It's likely prone to be somewhat less than java for comparable tasks but that is not a hard and fast rule.  The only way to tell how much memory you need is by looking how much memory is being used when you are doing what you want to do.